# Number of Page Table Entries

Tags: equation, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

This is a problem in a computer architecture course.  I'm not exactly sure how to determine the answer, so I wanted to double check to see if I'm understanding this correctly:

Determine the number of page table entries if:
32b VA, 2GB physical memory, 8kB pages, 8B PTE.

This is how I derived my solution:
(2^32)/(2^13) = 2^19 entries, since each page fetched will have 2^13 bytes and is byte addressable, requiring an offset of 13b in the VA, leaving 32-13 = 19b to index the entries.

Does that sound correct?

Comment: This would depend on the page table format among other factors. If all 2 GiB of physical memory (ignoring memory-mapped I/O pages), were mapped in a single address space/page table with no aliasing then there would be 2 GiB/8 KiB *valid* PTEs. (With the use of a zero page, aliasing would be likely.) A hash-based page table could approach this limit of *defined* PTEs (including invalid entries) with a high load factor and chaining for collisions. In a hierarchical page table, if every leaf table was fully used there would be 2 GiB/8KiB PTEs (other addresses marked invalid at PDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds correct since it seems you are assuming only 1-level of page table in VA to PA translation. This calculation would change if you go for 2-level or 3-level page table translation and based on number of levels  and number of entries in each level VA bits would be split.